# How to get data from previous years till previous month using SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to fetch 2years data till 28-feb-2021 using SQL.

Example,
current date : 2021-03-17
start date = 2019-02-28
end date = 2021-02-28

This is the logic I'm using to fetch previous one month data:

```
DATEPART(m, date) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate())) AND
DATEPART(yyyy, date) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
```

Same kind of logic has to be implemented to retrieve 2 years of data.

Thanks in Advance,
Lakshmi S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to fetch 2years data till 28-feb-2021 using SQL.

The logic for this is:

```
date >= '2019-03-01' and
date < '2021-03-01'
```

To base this on the current date:

```
date >= dateadd(year, -2, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)) and
date < datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)
```